# advice on how to compare the exact order and contents of multiple arrays

Tags: javascript

At the moment I'm trying to compare the contents of 2 arrays using the for..in loop but with no success. I'm familiar with how to get the contents of each array separately but not sure how to then match each of these contents up. Basically if 2 values in the same index values of the array don't match I want to return false else carry on. My latest attempt I've tried placing both arrays in the same for..in using different variables then comparing these. If anyone could advise on this that would be great.

JS

```
var list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
var list2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'e'];

var i, j;
for (i in list1 && j in list2) {

    if (list1[i] !== list2[j]) {
        return false
    } else {
        return true
    }
}

/*for ( j in list2 ) {
console.log( list2[j] )        
}*/​
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Iteration over the elements of an array is done using the normal for loop:

```
if (list1.length != list2.length) {
    // Different length, cannot be equal
    return false;
}

// Check if there is a mismatch
for (var i = 0; i < list1.length; i++) {
    if (list1[i] !== list2[i]) {
        return false; // Return here, because we don't need to compare the rest
    }
}

return true;
```

Comment: Awesome, for some reason I always get it in my head that for..in is the call to make!

Answer (score 2):

```
var i, l = list1.length;

for( i = 0; i < l; ++i ) {
    if( list1[i] !== list2[i] ) {
        return false; //Compare one by one
    }
}

if( i !== list2.length ) {
    return false; // In case list2 was longer than list1
}

return true;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular loop for that, and don't return `true` inside the loop, then you will only compare the first elements:

```
for (var i = 0; i < list1.length; i++) {
    if (list1[i] !== list2[i]) {
        return false
    }
}
return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

That only the simplest way to solve problem on sample data which were in question, rather as  curiosity.

```
 return list1.toString() == list2.toString();
```

It will works with the most of data exluding: strings with commas and checking for types equality.

btw.

I found other way, i think - to discuss:

```
return   !(list1<list2 || list1>list2);
```

anyone?

Comment: Consider this: `["a,b"].toString() == ["a","b"].toString()`

Comment: Smart ideas! But both fail for cases where strict comparison is required, e.g. `["0"]` and `[0]`.